# Oracle number datatype

Tags: oracle

Number datatype has default precision of 39 or 40 and default scale value is zero.

```
declare 
i number; -- default will be i:= number(40,0)
```

however I can store this value in this.

```
i :=  120.45;
```

Same with precision, default was 40. but I can store 10^60 value also?

```
declare
i number;
begin
i := power(10,60);
dbms_output.put_line(i);
end;
/
```

Does this mean oracle automatic change precision and scale value accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle NUMBER datatype does *not* have a default scale of zero when a precision is unspecified. The scale defaults to zero only if a precision *is* specified.

The maximum precision that can be specified for the  NUMBER datatype is 38 decimal digits.

***Q:*** Does this mean oracle automatic change precision and scale value accordingly?

***A:***

If a precision and scale are not specified, then decimal point is not fixed and is allowed to "float". The NUMBER datatype can store the maximum range of values, POWER(10,-130) <= n < POWER(10,126).

If a precision is specified without a scale, e.g. NUMBER(38), then the scale defaults to zero. So that's equivalent to specifying NUMBER(38,0).

Answer (score 1):

Store the value that you give him and that is within the maximum and minimum range for the data type NUMBER.

Oracle Documentation:

column_name NUMBER

If a precision is not specified, the column stores values as given. If no scale is specified, the scale is zero

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT1832

Answer (score 1):

[The NUMBER type in Oracle is a portable, variable length (1 to 22 bytes), base 10 floating point data type with 38 decimal digits of precision](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF30020). IMO it is one of the best features of Oracle, as it effectively removes the need for developers to know or care about implementation-defined limits on how numeric values are stored. For variables or columns of type `NUMBER` there is no default scale; however, if a NUMBER is declared as e.g. `NUMBER(7)` then you are correct that the scale defaults to zero. In my experience it is extremely unusual to declare any NUMBER variable or column with either scale or precision, my preference being to let the chips fall as they may, numerically speaking, and then round or truncate as needed.